# How to add emoji to response from Bot Framework from WebChat?

Tags: botframework

I am trying to add emojis to web chat response from the bot. I have tried markdown but that doesn't seem to work. What would be the best way to include emojis in the response for a WebChat?

Comment: Are you using C# or NodeJS? Where are you editing your code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get emoji to work, you can use Unicode emoji for web chat. If you are creating the bot in C#, it is important to note that [Unicode is denoted through an escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction). I edited [my bot](http://disablecardbuttonbot20170308111118.azurewebsites.net/) in Visual Studio.

The code for the reply looks like this:

```
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text}. \U0001F600 Your greeting status is {SentGreeting}");
```

In this case, the emoji I am using is within the code as: `\U0001F600`

`\U` is the escape sequence that C# will recognize, and note the three `000`'s that are added in place of the '+' when retrieving emoji from [Unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/full-emoji-list.html#1f600) standard format.

Edit: from @mgbennet: For Nodejs, you can use the surrogates of the emoji unicode to get them to display using `String.fromCharCode(0xD83D, 0xDE01)`

Comment: If you want add a Unicode emoji in Node.js, you can use `"Message text with a " + String.fromCharCode(0xD83D, 0xDE01) + " in it"` to get "Message text with a  in it". See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985851/how-to-render-32bit-unicode-characters-in-google-v8-and-nodejs).

Comment: to be more specific, you don't really want "fromCharCode" as then you need to deal with more unicode complexity than you want - epecially for high value codepoints. You really want the function that can just take the 32-bit codepoint, which is much easier:

Docs found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/string-fromcodepoint-function-javascript
... or here (with good examples):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

Comment: Direct on Visual Studio works fine, but if the codes comes from a variable I was not able to make it work from a text stored in database.

var response = "You sent \U0001F600"

Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(response);