# Upload documents is not working on QnA Maker

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Uploading documents to QnA maker is not consistent and has many bug.

I am trying to create a multiturn question base for corona virus information, but the uploaded document will not work nor be parsed even that I went by all the rules over the document.

If i use the sample document it will work, but changing anything will make the document fail dramatically.

you can see the document on the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aGl6fF6JT3CYxWj5WFMgZCHo8AWmlNH_

Comment: What exactly is failing? And by multiturn, do you mean you want to have prompts in the answers to link to additional answers?

Comment: the multiturn feature is to connect multiple question on top of each other like a pyramid, a question will lead to another and another until you reach and end, and some question will be unavailable outside the pyramid
my problem is the that after i followed the document specification on msdn the document will not generate multiturn question and will start to behave weirdly

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the [Building your own multi-turn document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#building-your-own-multi-turn-document) guidelines which are:

> - Use headings and sub-headings to denote hierarchy. For example You can h1 to denote the parent QnA and h2 to denote the QnA that should
>     be taken as prompt. Use small heading size to denote subsequent
>     hierarchy. Don't use style, color, or some other mechanism to imply
>     structure in your document, QnA Maker will not extract the multi-turn
>     prompts.
> - First character of heading must be capitalized.
> - Do not end a heading with a question mark, ?.
> - You can use the sample document as an example to create your own multi-turn document.

It seems to me that you are violating the `Do not end a heading with a question mark, ?` rule.

If removing the question marks from the headers does not fix the issue, I suggest trying the following:

1. Downloading the [sample document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/blob/master/qna-maker/data-source-formats/multi-turn.docx) that is linked on the page above and replacing the content with your own content but keeping the same fonts to see if that works.
2. Removing the emoji's from the start of your content to see if that has any effect as this might [cause issues](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2224), try using the unicode representations as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654936/how-to-add-emoji-to-response-from-bot-framework-from-webchat/42770295).
3. Combining the above approaches.

Hopefully this helps