# How can I insert emoji unicode in Language Generation file template?

Tags: botframework

I can't show emoji using unicode in the template.lg in bot framework emulator.

```
# ContactBot
- Thank you. Don't hesitate to contact me anytime. \U0001F60A
```

Comment: Which program language you are using? Node.js?

Comment: I hope this one will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654936/how-to-add-emoji-to-response-from-bot-framework-from-webchat/42770295#42770295

Comment: @karthicknagarajan I'm using C#

Comment: That `\U...` is for UTF-32, Two 2-byte chars in UTF-16 encoding for U+1F60A might be supported. First try with `&#x1F60A;` (a numeric entity). Conversion from UTF-32 to UTF-16 needs programming or some list. There is also https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/4/smileys-people/smiling-face - with which I have no experience.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16 in C#. To read 32 bits Unicode, there is this `Encoding.UTF32`. [Link on MSDN for Encoding.​UT​F32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf32encoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)